# North of <<number>>

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning

I haven't succeed with a research of the phrase below cited from the House M.D. - Love Hurts, episode 7x06.

Dr. Lisa Cuddy:

> The two of you have a combined IQ north of 300.

What does **north of xxx** means in case of using with a number, not direction?

Where is likely the usage of this phrase and in what situations?

Do exist another phrases using others of he world sides (sout, west, east) in a similar context?

Comment: English uses directions in peculiar ways in a few contexts: bigger, as in *north of xxx*, as you used; and deteriorating or falling apart, particularly a situation, as in "the entire company is going south", to list a couple.  I can't think of any non-standard usages of *east* or *west*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On a [standard map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map), north is on ***top***, south on the ***bottom*** (and east / west right and left respectively).

This image is the base for using north / south *figuratively*:

- If something is *north of*, it's ***above*** or ***over***,
- if it's *south of*, it's ***below*** the value or threshold mentioned in the context.

So you can rephrase your example as

> ... a combined IQ **over** 300.

(East and west are rarely used in a similarly figurative sense.)

Comment: Sounds reasonable, thanks for the answer. Do you know in what places I can hear this phrase more likely?

Comment: Related, with origins and several examples: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42358/origin-of-the-idiom-go-south

Comment: It could be used in any context related to a measurement or amount, such as a weight or an amount of money. It seems to me that using it with a period of time (e.g., “I’ve lived here for north of twenty-five years”) would be awkward but understandable.

Comment: The enemy's gate is down.

Comment: ^ [Explanation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game)

Answer (score 2):

The sentence means that they have a combined IQ above 300.

You can find the definition here: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/north-of-sth